# Not copying over duplicate rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question on how to add onto to this code to not copy duplicate rows.  My columns A, C, and D  combined together would make an unique identifier, but I'd rather not have to add that "helper" column to my spreadsheet if possible.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRows()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws1r As Range, ws2r As Range
    Dim ws1lr As Long, ws1lc As Long, ws2lr As Long, i As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")

    ws1lr = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        'last row in "2"
    ws1lc = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last col in "2"
    ws2lr = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1    'last row in "Core_Cutter"

    For i = 1 To ws1lr

        If Len(ws1.Cells(i, "A")) > 0 And Len(ws1.Cells(i, "G")) = 0 Then

            Set ws1r = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, ws1lc))
            Set ws2r = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(ws2lr, 1), ws2.Cells(ws2lr, ws1lc))

            ws2r.Value2 = ws1r.Value2
            ws2lr = ws2lr + 1
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggesting adding a for..next loop prior to the existing one, and in that for..next loop make an array containing the unique identifier for each row (made from cells in A,C,D).  Then you can use that array to ensure no changes are made in the following for..next loop if a row already has been done.

I threw the code below together quick and have no simple way to check it without your data, so it will require modification. But at least it gives you an idea. Let me know if you have questions.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRows()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws1r As Range, ws2r As Range
    Dim ws1lr As Long, ws1lc As Long, ws2lr As Long, i As Long
    Dim copyArr() As String, aCopy As Boolean, j As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")

    ws1lr = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        'last row in "2"
    ws1lc = ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last col in "2"
    ws2lr = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1    'last row in "Core_Cutter"

    ReDim copyArr(1 To ws1lr) As String
    For i = 1 To ws1lr
      copyArr(i) = ws1.Cells(i, "A") + ws1.Cells(i, "C") + ws1.Cells(i, "D")
    Next

    For i = 1 To ws1lr
      aCopy = False
      For j = 1 To ws1lr
        If i <> j And copyArr(i) = copyArr(j) Then
          aCopy = True
          Exit For
        End If
      Next j

      If Not aCopy Then

        If Len(ws1.Cells(i, "A")) > 0 And Len(ws1.Cells(i, "G")) = 0 Then

            Set ws1r = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Cells(i, ws1lc))
            Set ws2r = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(ws2lr, 1), ws2.Cells(ws2lr, ws1lc))

            ws2r.Value2 = ws1r.Value2
            ws2lr = ws2lr + 1
        End If

      End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Here's a test sub to troubleshoot the code you're having trouble with. Because the value of 7 3/4 you mention in your comment could give trouble for Excel cells, I formatted the cells in column A as text.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, s As String
Dim i As Integer, copyArr() As String
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
ReDim copyArr(1 To 3) As String
For i = 1 To 3
  copyArr(i) = CStr(ws1.Cells(i, "A")) + CStr(ws1.Cells(i, "C")) + CStr(ws1.Cells(i, "D"))
  ws1.Cells(i, "D") = copyArr(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I appreciate you writing this up.  One problem, I am getting an error "Run Time Error '13'  Type mismatch and the debugger brings me back to this section of the code:   copyArr(i) = ws1.Cells(i, "A") + ws1.Cells(i, "C") + ws1.Cells(i, "D")

Comment: The point of that line is to combine the content of each cell to come up with your unique identifier, but not knowing what's in your cells, I'm not sure what the problem might be. Try wrapping each with cstr() to ensure you are just adding strings. That is, the new line will be: CStr(ws1.Cells(i, "A")) + CStr(ws1.Cells(i, "C")) + CStr(ws1.Cells(i, "D"))

Comment: Hrmm... that update still bugged out.  I'm trying to send you a screen shot of the data but it's not letting me paste it.  In column A, I have an order number (ex. DL59488) then column C, I have a quantity (ex. 13), and column D has a dimension (ex. 7 3/4 or 20 IN)

Comment: The 7 3/4 could be a problem for Excel since it may be converted to 7.75 etc... depending on the formatting. For that reason I suggest formatting the cells in that column as text. I've added a small test sub to my original answer to troubleshoot the problem you describe. I also included an animated gif showing it running to confirm that it works fine for me.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but now it is pasting everything into column D of spreadsheet 2 instead of column A in the core cutter list spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry it's causing you problems. As I'm sure you understand, Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, but there is a lot of help and pointers here if you can break your problem into small pieces and provide specific examples (I see that paul bica has offered another approach). Hopefully I've helped shed a little light...

Answer (score 0):

This approach is using a dictionary to capture records already present in "Core_Cutter_List"
If a record already exists in the second sheet it will not copy it again from the first sheet ("2")

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRows()
    Const A = 1, C = 3, D = 4, IDK = "|"
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long, recordID As String
    Dim ws1ur As Variant, ws2ur As Variant, ws1lc As Long, dic As Object

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")

    ws1ur = ws1.UsedRange           'all data in "2" (as array)
    ws2ur = ws2.UsedRange           'all data in "Core_Cutter" (as array)
    ws1lc = UBound(ws1ur, 2)        'last col in "2"
    j = UBound(ws2ur, 1) + 1        'last row in "Core_Cutter"

    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  'Capture IDs in ws2, cols A, C, & D
    For i = 1 To j - 1
        dic(ws2ur(i, A) & IDK & ws2ur(i, C) & IDK & ws2ur(i, D)) = 0
    Next i

    For i = 1 To UBound(ws1ur, 1)   'last row in "2"

        If Len(ws1ur(i, 1)) > 0 And Len(ws1ur(i, 7)) = 0 Then

            recordID = ws1ur(i, A) & IDK & ws1ur(i, C) & IDK & ws1ur(i, D)

            If Not dic.Exists(recordID) Then  'check that the record in ws1 is not in ws2
                dic(recordID) = 0             'add it to the dictionary
                ws2.UsedRange.Rows(j).Value2 = ws1.UsedRange.Rows(i).Value2  'Copy rows
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Test data in Worksheets("2")

[image: Worksheets("2")]

Result - Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")

[image: Worksheets("Core_Cutter_List")]